# How do I delay/defer/control when an A-Frame scene initializes/loads?

Tags: aframe

I want to have an A-Frame scene start loading only when I tell it to. Currently if I put `<a-scene>` in an HTML file, it will start initializing immediately.

```
<a-scene></a-scene>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An A-Frame scene waits for all of its children to initialize before it itself initializes. So it waits for every `<a-entity>` from the bottom up. Under the hood, `<a-entity>` is based on `<a-node>` which handles load order. When `<a-node>` emits `loaded`, then the parent nodes can begin loading. `<a-entity>` emits `loaded` when it attaches + initializes all of its components.

Therefore, you start a scene on demand:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-node id="waitOnMe"></a-node>
</a-scene>

document.getElementById('waitOnMe').emit('loaded');  // When you are ready.
```