# How to stop A-frame from rendering?

Tags: aframe

I read the [documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/scene.html) about the scene entity that's responsible for rendering the scene, but I didn't find anything regarding stopping the rendering to happen.

**Question**: Is there a way to halt the rendering?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can completely stop the rendering, however you can pause specific entities or the scene:

https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/entity.html#pause

Here's a demo, it waits for the scene to load, and then calls the pause function on the scene, which pauses all components and entities in the scene.

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-pause-scene-on-load

```
<a-scene>
  <a-node id="waitOnMe"></a-node>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" shadow>
    <a-animation attribute="rotation"
           dur="10000"
           fill="forwards"
           to="0 360 0"
           repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>
  </a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E" shadow></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D" shadow></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" shadow></a-plane>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Note: I've added an a-node element to guarantee it catches the load event at the end of the page.

Then the js to pause:

```
<script>
  var scene = document.querySelector('a-scene')
  scene.addEventListener('loaded', function () { 
    scene.pause();
  });
  document.getElementById('waitOnMe').emit('loaded');
</script>
```

Related info about waiting for load can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47363072/8005106

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any satisfactory answer to this, so here's how I managed to stop it (and also start it when needed):

```
let sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
let renderer = sceneEl.renderer;

// Stop rendering
renderer.setAnimationLoop(null);

// Start rendering, personally i set this inside a button click
renderer.setAnimationLoop(sceneEl.render);
```